# How to stream data from Kafka topic to Delta table using Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

I'm trying to understand databricks delta and thinking to do a POC using Kafka. Basically the plan is to consume data from Kafka and insert it to the databricks delta table.

These are the steps that I did:

1. **Create a delta table on databricks.**

```
%sql
CREATE TABLE hazriq_delta_trial2 (
  value STRING
)
USING delta
LOCATION '/delta/hazriq_delta_trial2'
```

2. **Consume data from Kafka.**

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    
val kafkaBrokers = "broker1:port,broker2:port,broker3:port"
val kafkaTopic = "kafkapoc"
    
val kafka2 = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBrokers)
  .option("subscribe", kafkaTopic)
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 100)
  .load()
  .select($"value")
  .withColumn("Value", $"value".cast(StringType))
  .writeStream
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/delta/hazriq_delta_trial2/_checkpoints/test")
  .table("hazriq_delta_trial2")
```

**However, when I query the table, it is empty.**

I can confirm that the data is coming. I verify it by seeing the spike in the graph when I produce a message to the Kafka topic.

[image: incoming data]

Am I missing something?

I need help on how I can insert the data that I get from Kafka into the table.

Answer (score 4):

Below is a working example on how to read data from Kafka and stream it into a delta table. I was using Spark 3.0.1 and delta-core 0.7.0 (if you are on Spark 2.4 version you need to use 0.6.0).

### Streaming data from Kafka into Delta table

```scala
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("Kafka2Delta")
  .master("local[*]")
  .getOrCreate()

// in production this should be a more reliable location such as HDFS
val deltaPath = "file:///tmp/delta/table"

val df = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "test")
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
  .load()
  .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as value")

val query: StreamingQuery = df.writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/path/to/sparkCheckpoint")
  .start(deltaPath)

query.awaitTermination()
```

For testing, I have simply produced characters "a", "b", "c" and "d" as values into the Kafka topic. Obviously, you can build some more sophisticated Dataframes if the Kafka input data is e.g. a JSON string.

### Checking data in Delta table

```
val table = spark.read
  .format("delta")
  .load(deltaPath)
  .createOrReplaceTempView("testTable")

spark.sql("SELECT * FROM testTable").show(false)

// result
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|a    |
|b    |
|c    |
|d    |
+-----+
```

### Files created in deltaPath

```
>/tmp/delta/table$ ll
total 44
drwxrwxr-x 3 x x 4096 Jan 11 17:12 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 x x 4096 Jan 11 17:10 ../
drwxrwxr-x 2 x x 4096 Jan 11 17:12 _delta_log/
-rw-r--r-- 1 x x  414 Jan 11 17:12 part-00000-0a0ae7fb-2995-4da4-8284-1ab85899fe9c-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 x x   12 Jan 11 17:12 .part-00000-0a0ae7fb-2995-4da4-8284-1ab85899fe9c-c000.snappy.parquet.crc
-rw-r--r-- 1 x x  306 Jan 11 17:12 part-00000-37eb0bb2-cd27-42a4-9db3-b79cb046b638-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 x x   12 Jan 11 17:12 .part-00000-37eb0bb2-cd27-42a4-9db3-b79cb046b638-c000.snappy.parquet.crc
-rw-r--r-- 1 x x  414 Jan 11 17:12 part-00000-8d6b4236-1a12-4054-b016-3db7a007cbab-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 x x   12 Jan 11 17:12 .part-00000-8d6b4236-1a12-4054-b016-3db7a007cbab-c000.snappy.parquet.crc
-rw-r--r-- 1 x x  407 Jan 11 17:12 part-00000-d2612eaa-3f48-4708-bf90-31dd3d83f124-c000.snappy.parquet
-rw-r--r-- 1 x x   12 Jan 11 17:12 .part-00000-d2612eaa-3f48-4708-bf90-31dd3d83f124-c000.snappy.parquet.crc
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to verify if you have access to Kafka from your Spark cluster, sometimes you need to allow the access from some ips in Kafka.

2) Try to change this `.option("startingOffsets", "earliest"`) to this `.option("startingOffsets", "latest")`

3) Try also

```
val kafka2 = spark.readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBrokers)
  .option("subscribe", kafkaTopic)
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .load()
  .select($"value")
  .withColumn("Value", $"value".cast(StringType))
  .writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .outputMode("append")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/delta/hazriq_delta_trial2/_checkpoints/test")
  .start("hazriq_delta_trial2")
```